# Give an Object a Method in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to give a C# Object like

```
public string Name
{
  get { return _name; }
  set { _name = value; }
}
```

a Method doing something like:

```
private void addTextToName(){
  _name = _name + " - Test";
}
```

so that I can call it like

```
Name.addTextToName();
```

Because (where I come from) in JavaScript you can do such things with .prototype

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: `Name` in your example is a `string`, not a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the extension method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.Name = "Hello World";
        var x = e.Name;
        var y = x.addTextToName();
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
class Example
{
    public string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string addTextToName(this string str)
    {
        return str += " - Test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking *can I add a method to a string?* then yes.  Look at extension methods.

```
public static string AddTextToName(this string s)
{
    return s + " - Test";
}
```

Use it like this:

```
"Hello".AddTextToName();
```

Will return `Hello - test`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way for C# Objects (you used a string there, but though...).

Take a look at the so-called "extension methods" in C# as they are exactly what you need I think.

For further reference, look e.g. here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (the magic is in the `this` as parameter for the method)